# Honeywell RTH9585WF Thermostat wiring question

Tags: wiring, thermostat-c-wire

My old thermostat LUXPRO TX 9600tsa uses 4 wires:

- W white
- G green
- R red hooked to RH and looped to RC and
- Y yellow

This thing is not working right, so I purchased a Honeywell RTH9585WF WiFi thermostat.  The issue is I have is no C wire and on this new one there is no RH block so I hooked the R red to red but do I need to loop it to RC to get power?

I was also told I could relocate the G to C and go that route. just not sure what to do?   I am getting no power to it...

Answer (score 0):

The RTH9585WF should have a Rh/Rc jumper from the factory, if it is missing then you must add one. If you use the green wire as a "c" wire you need to change it on the thermostat and in the air conditioner. You will lose the "fan only" option at the stat.